# JAVA ObjectNode get is empty

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

My JSON in my @RequestBody ObjectNode objectNode

```
{
    "script":
        {"id":2,"nom":"tes","libelleprerequiss":
        [{"id":1,"libelle_prerequis":"Soc devis VAM","produit":{"id":1,"nom":"VAM"},"typologie":{"id":1,"nom":"devis"}}]
        },
    "libellePrerequis":
        {"id":3,"libelle_prerequis":"Soc contrat VAM","produit":{"id":1,"nom":"VAM"},"typologie":{"id":2,"nom":"contrat"}
        }
}
```

When i do :

```
    String id_script = objectNode.get("script").get("id").asText();
    String id_libelleprerequis = objectNode.get("libellePrerequis").get("id").asText();
    System.out.println("Script ID = " + id_script + "...");
    System.out.println("Libelle Prerequis ID = " + id_libelleprerequis + "...");
```

i Have a result :

```
Update Script - Script ID = 2...
Update Script - Libelle Prerequis ID = 3...
```

But when i do :

```
String libelleprerequis = objectNode.get("libellePrerequis").asText();
System.out.println("Update Script - Libelle Prerequis = " + libelleprerequis + "...");
```

I have :

```
Update Script - Libelle Prerequis = ...
```

I would like to recover my "LibellePrerequis" to integrate it to my script in my entity (many to many)

Comment: Just a quick question what is the result of doing `objectNode.get("libellePrerequis").isValueNode();` ?

Comment: value is "false"

Comment: Have you tried `objectNode.get("libellePrerequis").toString();`?

Comment: I do not know why I was sure I tried, and no! I just put this and it works. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"libellePrerequis"` is an object.

`asText()` works only if your node is a value.

You can check with `objectNode.get("libellePrerequis").isValueNode();`

To get a node object as String, you need to use `toString()`:

```
objectNode.get("libellePrerequis").toString();
```

**EDIT1:**

To transform your node into object you need to create some objects which represent the tree of your node.

```
public class Libell{

    private int id;
    private String libelle_prerequis;
    private Produit produit;
    private Typologie typologie;

    //getters, setters

}

public class Typologie{

    private int id;
    private String nom;

    //getters, setters

}

public class Produit{

    private int id;
    private String nom;

    //getters, setters

}
```

The most important thing is to have the same name for attributes(`id, libelle_prerequis, ...`) as in `json` and pay attention to their type. So the name of objects (`Libell`, `Typologie` and `Produit`) doesn't matter if their structure is like in `json`.

Now, to map your `JSonNode` to an object you can do this:

```
ObjectMapper objMap = new ObjectMapper();

Libell libell = objMap.convertValue(objectNode.get("libellePrerequis"), Libell.class);

System.out.println(libell.getId());
System.out.println(libell.getProduit().getId());
System.out.println(libell.getTypologie().getId());
```